# detect unchecked checkbox php

Tags: php

Is there a way to check of a checkbox is unchecked with php? I know you can do a hidden field type in html but what about with just php when the form is submitted? I tried below no luck.

```
if(!isset($_POST['server'])||$_POST['server']!="yes"){
        $_POST['server']     == "No";
}
```

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked it will not be posted. `if(!isset($_POST['checkboxname']))` will do the trick.

Comment: You can't - there's nothing submitted for an unchecked checkbox (as opposed to an empty string which is what you get with, for example, an empty text field.) All you can do is go through the checkboxes that should be there, and check to see which ones are set.

Comment: @Matt I tried that, but nothing was echo'd dial_terminal `if(!isset($_POST['server'])) {$_POST['server'] == "No";}`

Comment: What happens when you call `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @Matt all post values show except for the unchecked checkboxs

Comment: OK, so then `if(!isset($_POST['checkboxname']))` will verify that they haven't been checked. Test the value in a separate `if` statement. That might be what's throwing you off.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a checkbox is not checked it will not be posted. `if(!isset($_POST['checkboxname']))` will do the trick.

Be aware, though, you should at least submit *something* so that you know the form was submitted in the first place.

```
if (isset($_POST['formWasSubmitted'])) {
    //form was submitted...let's DO this.

    if (!isset($_POST['checkboxname'])) {
        // checkbox was not checked...do something
    } else {
        // checkbox was checked. Rock on!
    }
}
```

Comment: i got it to work. I rewrote the form... there was an error that was throwing it off

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for people looking for this....

Better approach to Matt's answer is to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check if form was submitted:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    //form was submitted...let's DO this.

    if (!isset($_POST['checkboxname'])) {
        // checkbox was not checked...do something
    } else {
        // checkbox was checked. Rock on!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$checkedfeild = @$_POST["yourfeildname"];

if(isset($checkedfeild))
{
 //Code here
}
else
{
echo"Not checked";
}
```

Comment: ...and what if `$_POST['yourfieldname']` isn't set?

Comment: This is bad style, unclean programming. You do not check if array key exists, you do not got implicit condition in your if(). Do not teach newbies bad habits. They may one day end writing the app you would be using.

Comment: isn't set? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the index doesn't exist. There's nothing else I *could* mean.

Comment: This will throw a notice on line #1

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$checked = $_POST['notif'];
foreach($checked as $ch){
    if($ch == $i){
       /add element to checked set
       $array_checked[]=$ch;
    }
}
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
    if(in_array($i,$array_checked)){
        //do for checked
    }else{
        //do for unchecked
    }
}
```